# Why different output from math expression nest in function vs. called directly?

Tags: r

Struct a weird effect in R. When coding a math expression as a function you get a different output than when coded directly? Any good explanations/solutions?

```
myfun <- function(x) x^(1/4)

myfun(-238194.65)
```

Returns: NaN

```
-238194.65^(1/4)
```

Returns: -22.0919

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the order of operations.
`myfun(-238194.65)` is interpreted as `(-238194.65)^(1/4)` because `x = -238194.65`.

On the other hand, `-238194.65^(1/4)` is equal to `-(238194.65^(1/4))` because the exponentiation is done before. The solution is to add parentheses to indicate more clearly the order of the operations you want to realize.